# pytest - mock process and time

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I have following method for testing right log format.

```
@patch('sys.stderr', new_callable=StringIO)
    @mock.patch('socket.gethostname', return_value='testing')
    def test_logging(self, gethostname_function, mock_stderr):
        logger = logging.getLogger('project.logging')
        app_logging.init_logging()

        logger.info('testing mesage')


        assert mock_stderr.getvalue() == '{"message": "testing mesage", "levelname": "INFO", "process": 37284, "asctime": "2018-03-01 13:23:33,968", "hostname": "testing"}\n'
```

where formatter looks like this:

```
(message) (levelname) (process) (asctime)
```

How can I mock datetime and process id? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok,

```
@patch('time.time', mock_time)
@patch('os.getpid', mock_os_pid)
```

is the solution. Sorry, for waste your time :)